# Android Design Support Library not compiling

Tags: android, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport

I'm trying to add in the new Design Support library but it won't compile.

Before making the following changes, my code compiled perfectly fine.

I tried adding it using:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

And I removed:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
```

Since the design support library has these two libraries inside it. However, my app won't compile!!

I get the following error:

```
Warning:Dependency xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c is ignored for productionDebug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
     In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
```

This error is repeated 4 times for each of my flavours (production/stagingDebug/Release).

It then lists a bunch of image errors such as:

```
/Users/.../app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_chat.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
```

Then finally after a bunch of common output, it says:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexStagingDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Pls help :(

Comment: Images errors `iCCP` can be ignored. And your problem seems related to `xpp3` library, not design not support. XPP3 library seem to embed another version of the support libraries.

Comment: run `./gradlew app:dependencies` to check if redundant dependencies are not being excluded. If there are, exclude them (ie `exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-ads'`)

Comment: that two libs you removed is for your project not the support library, you need to maintain those two lines you omitted

Comment: @tibo, I did that and found that one of my libs was using xpp3 so I removed it like you mentioned, then the first error (related to xpp3) was removed, but the second one (..finished with non-zero exit value 2) is still remaining. Any ideas?

Comment: @Elltz, see: http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html where they mention that, "Note that as the Design library depends on the Support v4 and AppCompat Support Libraries, those will be included automatically when you add the Design library dependency."

Comment: For the second one, you need to use java 7 (jdk1.7.0_75.jdk or above)

Comment: But I need java 8 to compile using Lollipop, no?

Comment: No, java 8 is not yet supported.

Comment: That didn't do it. I still get the same error but now referencing jdk1.7 instead of jdk1.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In app gradle add this to defaultConfig

multiDexEnabled = true

Comment: Although this isn't all that's required, the issue indeed was with multidex. I fixed the issue a while ago. You're answer is only part of the solution. I'll give you the correct answer anyway.

Comment: I have given all the steps. plz see

Comment: i got the answer on this page [http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

Answer (score 1):

1:- Add this Line to Manifest
Application
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"

2:- In app gradle add this to defaultConfig

```
 multiDexEnabled = true
```

3:-add this in Gradle app dependencies

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

Now you won't get any exception its pure solution. :) Enjoy